# What is the name of this proof in linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, terminology

I've been asked to prove the following statement. However, I don't know where to start and have no intuition on why it should be true. I'd like to research this proof online but don't know the name:

> Suppose $A$ is a basis for a vector space $V$.
>
> Pick an element $a \in A$ and a linear combination $b := a_0a + \sum \alpha_ia_i$ where $a_i \neq a, a_0 \neq 0$ Then $B:= (A \setminus \{a\}) \cup \{b\}$ is again a basis for $V$

I think this is similar to the replacement theorem but worded differently?

Comment: Why don't you just try to prove it directly? Show the set is spanning and linearly independent. Hint: in order to show it spans $V$ it is sufficient to prove all the elements of $A$ belong to the span of $B$. (so you don't even need to consider a general element in $V$)

Comment: I think that you are missing the hypothesis that all the $a_i\in A$?

Comment: As an aside, I would recommend not getting into a habit of looking up a proof when you encounter a challenging exercise. Getting more comfortable trying things out and exploring examples (especially when you don't know where to start and have no intuition) is a skill/muscle worth developing, especially as exercises get harder.

Answer (score 3):

It's the Steinitz exchange lemma. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz_exchange_lemma